Table with sticky transparent background headers
I have a table that has a transparent header row
I want the header row to be sticky but when I do that when I scroll vertically the table the other table rows are scrolling behind the header and since it is transparent, it is shown.
table
behind the header
I tried making only the <tbody> element scrollable but that makes things difficult since the scrollbar now pushes the tbody to the left when it appears leaving the tbody not horizontally aligned with the <thead>


table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
}

td {
  background-color: brown;
}

.sticky-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}
 <table>
            <thead>
                <tr class="sticky-header">
                    <th>Header 1</th>
                    <th>Header 2</th>
                    <th>Header 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody>
                <tr><td>Row 1, Col 1</td><td>Row 1, Col 2</td><td>Row 1, Col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Row 2, Col 1</td><td>Row 2, Col 2</td><td>Row 2, Col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Row 3, Col 1</td><td>Row 3, Col 2</td><td>Row 3, Col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Row 4, Col 1</td><td>Row 4, Col 2</td><td>Row 4, Col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Row 5, Col 1</td><td>Row 5, Col 2</td><td>Row 5, Col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Row 6, Col 1</td><td>Row 6, Col 2</td><td>Row 6, Col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Row 7, Col 1</td><td>Row 7, Col 2</td><td>Row 7, Col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Row 8, Col 1</td><td>Row 8, Col 2</td><td>Row 8, Col 3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Row 9, Col 1</td><td>Row 9, Col 2</td><td>Row 9, Col 3</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>




can't you just add background-color: white to header ?

You want transparent header color only or you can change it and the table header should be fixed and the content under it should scroll right ?

Please explain why the background color needs to be transparent as there may be a way round it.



th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
}

td {
  background-color: brown;
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: scroll;
    }
thead{
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    z-index: 9;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
}

td {
  background-color: brown;
}

.sticky-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}
 <table>
        <thead>
            <tr class="sticky-header">
                <th>Header 1</th>
                <th>Header 2</th>
                <th>Header 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr><td>Row 1, Col 1</td><td>Row 1, Col 2</td><td>Row 1, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 2, Col 1</td><td>Row 2, Col 2</td><td>Row 2, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 3, Col 1</td><td>Row 3, Col 2</td><td>Row 3, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 4, Col 1</td><td>Row 4, Col 2</td><td>Row 4, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 5, Col 1</td><td>Row 5, Col 2</td><td>Row 5, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 6, Col 1</td><td>Row 6, Col 2</td><td>Row 6, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 7, Col 1</td><td>Row 7, Col 2</td><td>Row 7, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 8, Col 1</td><td>Row 8, Col 2</td><td>Row 8, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 9, Col 1</td><td>Row 9, Col 2</td><td>Row 9, Col 3</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>



I'll use the z-index with the top and left 0 with position sticky
and when it scrolls I'll blur the background. I think that might help you

You could try this below code:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sticky Header Table Example</title>
    <style>
        /* Basic table styling */
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th, td {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        /* Styling for the table rows */
        td {
            background-color: brown;
            color: white;
        }

        /* Sticky header styling */
        .sticky-header {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); /* Semi-transparent white */
            color: black; /* Text color for visibility */
            z-index: 1; /* Ensure it stays above the rows */
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr class="sticky-header">
                <th>Header 1</th>
                <th>Header 2</th>
                <th>Header 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Row 1, Col 1</td><td>Row 1, Col 2</td><td>Row 1, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 2, Col 1</td><td>Row 2, Col 2</td><td>Row 2, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 3, Col 1</td><td>Row 3, Col 2</td><td>Row 3, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 4, Col 1</td><td>Row 4, Col 2</td><td>Row 4, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 5, Col 1</td><td>Row 5, Col 2</td><td>Row 5, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 6, Col 1</td><td>Row 6, Col 2</td><td>Row 6, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 7, Col 1</td><td>Row 7, Col 2</td><td>Row 7, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 8, Col 1</td><td>Row 8, Col 2</td><td>Row 8, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 9, Col 1</td><td>Row 9, Col 2</td><td>Row 9, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 10, Col 1</td><td>Row 10, Col 2</td><td>Row 10, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 11, Col 1</td><td>Row 11, Col 2</td><td>Row 11, Col 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row 12, Col 1</td><td>Row 12, Col 2</td><td>Row 12, Col 3</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>



z-index: 1;  position: sticky; this will help the header to remains sticky at the top when scrolling and other part of the table you can scroll.


let me know if i misunderstood your issue
